# Characters typed won't appear in the command line when connected via TELNET

Tags: windows-xp, telnet, local, echo

On Windows XP, I changed the `localecho` field by setting it to `ON`, but after I quit telnet and make a connection in the command line, the `localecho` field is set again to `OFF`. Anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Windows telnet client sends data by lines. there is no way around. Use [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) or so.

> PuTTY is a free implementation of Telnet and SSH for Windows and Unix platforms, along with an xterm terminal emulator. It is written and maintained primarily by Simon Tatham.